# how would I look up C/C++ source code in Ubuntu Linux more conveniently and efficiently?

Tags: android, c++, c, eclipse, ubuntu

As we know , the **SourceInsight** is convenient to look up C/C++ source code on windows.

The **eclipse** is a good choice for java code .

I want to study the android source code ,but there isn't a convenient tool to look up the C/C++ code . When I analyze the invoking relationships of C/C++ code by simple text editor, it makes me a headache !

For example, I want to know the definition of method **getService()** which invoked in **frameworks/base/libs/ui/Camera.cpp**

```
binder = sm->getService(String16("media.camera"));
```

I will waste a large amount of time to find the invoking relationships.

But when I want to know the definition of java code by eclipse,like method **onCreate()** in **packages/apps/Camera/src/com/android/camera/Camera.java** , only one step is OK.

How would I look up C/C++ source code in Ubuntu Linux more conveniently and efficiently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ctags if you are using vi, or etags for emacs.

There is also [cscope](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/), which I was very impressed with when I used it many years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse (indigo) is also available for c++. Check out [here](http://www.eclipse.org/indigo/)

Comment: Plus eclipse greatly helps,you configure your build environment.

Comment: No, eclipse indigo. I had a very bad experience with CDT plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the Sublime Text 2 editor : http://www.sublimetext.com/2
it's a simple, fast and powerful editor :)
For example: you can define your snippets to make code writing fast, you can also search a word in all your projects files with a simple command and without having to open all the files ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use doxygen (www.doxygen.org) to generate cross-referencing web-pages from the source.