# C/C++ IDE with a indexer for ubuntu

Tags: android, c++, ubuntu

I have started doing Android Development on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Most of my work is developing low level drivers. Currently I am try to make modification to a LCD Controller for TI Sitara thus I work in a large code space (I understand large can be relative).

It has been challenge to trace code to understand a flow. It has been recommended that I look into an IDE with a Indexer.

1. Any thoughts on a IDE with a indexer
2. Guideline to tracing function calls etc in larger code space

I have read the following threads

1. [how would I look up C/C++ source code in Ubuntu Linux more conveniently and efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428218/how-would-i-look-up-c-c-source-code-in-ubuntu-linux-more-conveniently-and-effi?rq=1)
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149321/what-ide-would-be-good-for-linux-kernel-driver-development

Appreciate your thoughts

Comment: Eclipse has one... it's... finicky.

Comment: QtCreator has it, there is also a project to make a plugin that uses clang for it (which should be more accurate).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-cc-developers/keplerr) when I worked on the native side (C++) of an Android project code. I could not use the Eclipse packed with Android (Eclipse ADT, or something like that) as it never really worked indexing wise for the native code, but I could still edit the files and push the new code to the device from there. With the normal Eclipse, it will build an index of your code, and it will allow you to control click functions (which will take you to the declaration or the definition). It also will allow you to right click a function and find all of the uses of it within the project code space.